# mysql last 5 in reverse order?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `table1` WHERE id='0' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5
```

This is ok, it gets me the last 5 elements with the very last in the table being the first in the returned array.  ok.

But! I am trying to get the last 5 in normal table order (so the last in the main table would be number 5 in the returned array and the one before that would be 4 etc.)

I tried ASC, it didn't work...

How can I do this?

Comment: Since you are *filtering* for a single `id`, How do you define **last**, insertion order? Some other column?

Comment: Insertion order (id is on auto increment)

Comment: If `id` is a auto increment, thus (most likely) a `UNIQUE KEY`, your query will only return at most 1 row.

Comment: Please leave this question, it's a good references for other users. If you insist on having it deleted, flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: ok i'll leave it, but it does contain a serious error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your query a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html):

```
SELECT `name`
FROM (SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `table1` WHERE id='0' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5) tmp
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias?

Comment: Sorry, I can't check it exactly due to the question error but this is in the most correct direction.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select `name`
from (
   select `id`, `name`
   from `table1`
   where id='0'
   order by `id` desc
   limit 5
) as source
order by `id` asc
```

Comment: You see that there is a exact answer posted 5 minutes before yours, Is there anything you want to add? If yes, please update your answer, Otherwise please delete it and upvote Gumbo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity: use the dot I.e table1.name, e.g.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`date_of_rsvp` DESC";
```

I think this should work.